# Daily notification cannot start after installing

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm developing an android application that have daily notification. I have a solution but not enough. My code working after restarting the phone. Users will not restart their devices unless they are required. My notifications will not appear until this time. How can I solve?

BootReceiver.java

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Device Booted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, alarmIntent, 0);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }

    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver
    android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
<receiver
    android:name=".BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

AlarmReceiver.java -> just notification builder

Comment: You could set the same alarm from your launcher `Activity`, as well.

Comment: True, but i couldn't find any possible way

Comment: Well, if you don't want to repeat code, you could put all of the alarm code into a `static` method somewhere, with a `Context` parameter, since that's all you really need. Then, in the Receiver, call that method with the `Context` passed into `onReceive()`, and from the `Activity`, you'd just use the `Activity` itself – i.e., `this`, or `YourActivity.this`, as needed – since an `Activity` is a `Context`.